# What am I doing wrong in this attempt to convert an opencv function to lisp with cffi

Tags: opencv, common-lisp, cffi

The opencv function is cvSmooth and here is the cffi code I wrote

```
;; void cvSmooth(const CvArr* src, CvArr* dst, int smoothtype=CV_GAUSSIAN,
;;               int size1=3, int size2=0, double sigma1=0, double sigma2=0)

(defmacro defanonenum (&body enums)
  "Converts anonymous enums to Lisp constants."
  `(cl:progn ,@(cl:loop for value in enums
            for index = 0 then (cl:1+ index)
            when (cl:listp value) 
        do (cl:setf index (cl:second value)
                value (cl:first value))
        collect `(cl:defconstant ,value ,index))))

(defanonenum
  +gaussian+
  +blur+
  +blur-no-scale+
  +median+
  +bilateral+)
```

The C function interface:

```
(cffi:defcfun ("cvSmooth" %smooth) :void
  (src cv-array)                 ; source image
  (dest cv-array)                 ; destination image
  (smooth-type :int)
  (size1 :int)
  (size2 :int)
  (sigma1 :double)
  (sigma2 :double))

(defun smooth (src dest
               &optional
               (smooth-type +gaussian+)
               (size1 3)
               (size2 0)
               (sigma1 0)
               (sigma2 0))
  (%smooth src dest smooth-type size1 size2
           (coerce sigma1 'double-float)
           (coerce sigma2 'double-float)))
```

basically the +gaussian+  looks bad not like in opencv at all and +bilateral+ doesn't work at all  it makes the code I use it not even run but the rest work fine.....what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is really just a guess, based on something that happened to me recently. Since I see that you qualified `loop` and `setf` with package - is it possible that there were other problems related to where symbols are defined? For instance, you might've defined them elsewhere to have a different value, but then while you think you are using the correct constant you, in fact, use the one you defined before?

Comment: One small problem I see with the constant order. From the docs I think it is: +blur-no-scale+ +blur+
  +gaussian+
  +median+
  +bilateral+